# .htaccess redirect non-WWW to WWW

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to create .htaccess that will:

1. redirect all non-WWW url to WWW
2. redirect some spesific slugs to spesific pages
3. redirect all other slug (that no in the "spicel" to page.php?id=)

that what i use:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.co\.il
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.co.il/$1 [R=301,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^צרו-קשר$ /contact.php [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)$ /page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The url example.co.il not redirect wo www.example.co.il. What am I doing worng?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only redirects `non-www` to `www` when it's not an existing file/folder requested.
Simply remove those two conditions.

It becomes

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^צרו-קשר$ /contact.php [L]
# here: other specific pages

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)$ /page.php?id=$1 [L]
```